# How can I avoid one round from FOR JAVA

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to make an app "Secret Friend", I have this:

```
int start2;
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            start2 = random.nextInt(lista2.size() - 0) + 0;
            if (lista2.get(start2).equals(lista.get(i))) {
                break;
            } else {
                listaParejas.add(lista.get(i) + "->" + lista2.get(start2));
                listaSalidos.add(lista2.get(start2));
                lista2.remove(start2);
                //lista.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

lista and lista2 are shuffled, so for example lista has Daniel and lista2 has Michael, so listaParejas will have "Daniel->Michael", but sometima it would be like "Daniel->Daniel", so in the first ir I'm trying to avoid that, how can I make like that round with the first IF does not count int the FOR, thanks, I'm desperate, because I have had trying and trying, and nothing :(

Comment: What should happen when there is a coincidence? Program exits/shuffling is repeated/the pair is ignored? That is the first thing you should think about.

Answer (score 2):

How do you do in real life?

Do random assignations, if there is a mismatch repeat the entire process. If you are doing it for small groups of friends, it is fast to repeat. If you are doing it for large groups of friends, a mismatch is highly unlikely.

Another way of doing it:

You have the donnors and the recipients. The first donnor gets at random a paper strip with the name of his recipient; if there is no mismatch you retire both the donnor and the recipient (nobody is twice donnor, nobody is recipient twice). If a donnor (other than the last) gets his own paper, he choses another random recipient (or maybe just the next one available).

The only complicated case is when the last donnor retrieves the last strip of paper and finds his own name on it. In that case, you just need to swap it with any other donnor (if `Daniel->Daniel` is the last pair, you are sure that `Daniel` does not appear neither as donnor or recipient in any of the previous pairings, so you convert `Daniel->Daniel; John->Michael` in `Daniel->Michael; John->Daniel`).

You should really know how to solve the problem **BEFORE** writting the first line of code; solutions do not appear by themselves just by using a keyboard.